# Different `followPointer` behavior depending on series-type in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Currently I am working on having different `followPointer` behavior for different types of series in my Highchart implementation. For example, line charts in my project usually are closely bundled data points, so having `followPointer` set to true would not be great in terms of differentiating between closely packed data points, so for line series in a chart that ALSO contain a column/bar series, I'd like Highcharts to automatically switch to `followPointer: false` when it detects that the cursor is on a line chart.

I tried implementing it in the `tooltip.formatter` as demonstrated in this Fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/b7zmuh04/28/).

```
tooltip: {
     followPointer: true,
     formatter: function() {
            if(this.series.type == 'line') {
            this.series.tooltipOptions.followPointer = false;
        } else {
            this.series.tooltipOptions.followPointer = true;
        }
     }
},
```

The issue with this implementation is that it's very poor in performance as it will calculate and determine the type of series AND setting the `followPointer` variable on every mouse movement. It's obvious that is pretty bad for performance since it's re-calculating it many times a second.

So my question is - how do I maintain this behavior of adjusting `followPointer` depending on the series but in a performant way?

Comment: Could you add a column/bar series to your example so that we can better visualize the problem?

Comment: @KamilKulig woops, I thought I did that, but I forgot to update my Fiddle, only saved it. Updated with the working one.